# Join collections for TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a class called `LogEntry` which is definded as Following:

```
public class LogEntry
{
   public LogEntry()
   {
      Children = new List<LogEntry>();
   }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public int Id { get; set; }

   public List<LogEntry> Children { get; private set; }

   public override ToString()
   {
      return Name;
   }       
}
```

Through an interface to my application I get a List of `LogEntries` like

```
root -> sub1 -> subsub11 -> value111
root -> sub1 -> subsub11 -> value112
root -> sub1 -> subsub12 -> value121
root -> sub1 -> subsub12 -> value122
root -> sub1 -> subsub13 -> value131
root -> sub2 -> subsub21 -> value221
root -> sub3 -> subsub31 -> value331
root -> sub1 -> subsub12 -> value123
```

The `->` shows the only child in the children-collection of the current `LogEntry`.

Now I want to display this in a `TreeView` with a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. If I pass the collection directly to the `TreeView` with the following `TreeView`-Definition:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding HierarchicalLogEntries, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:LogEntry}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

With this each `LogEntry` is displayed as a single node. There I have 8 root-nodes with the same text.

My question now is: Is there an easy way to join these Objects togeter so that I have only one root-Element and all children also will be matched?

Comment: Technically, your "root" and "parent" `LogEntry` objects aren't the same, they just have same ids / names, right? So you have to join them manually in your view model, e.g. using Linq (`.GroupBy()`).

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should group / join your entries manually.

Here is an example how you could do this using linq's `GroupBy()` and a recursively called method. Note, that this is just an example and not the best approach.

Assuming you have an input collection `IEnumerable<LogEntry> entries` that holds your 'plain' data as you described, you could do something like this:

```
this.HierarchicalLogEntries.AddRange(this.Group(entries));
```

where the `Group()` method might look like:

```
IEnumerable<LogEntry> Group(IEnumerable<LogEntry> entries)
{
    List<LogEntry> result = new List<LogEntry>();

    var groups = entries.GroupBy(e => e.Id);
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        var children = group.SelectMany(e => e.Children);
        if (children.Any())
        {
            var key = group.First();
            LogEntry newItem = new LogEntry { Id = key.Id, Name = key.Name };
            newItem.Children.AddRange(Group(children));
            result.Add(newItem);
        }
        else
        {
            result.AddRange(group);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```